# Pyspark Function to Negate Column

Tags: pyspark, addition, negate

Is there a built-in function to add a new column which is the negation of the original column?

Spark SQL has the function `negative()`. Pyspark does not seem to have inherited this function.

```
df_new = df.withColumn(negative("orginal"))
```

Comment: I think you are asking:
```
df_new = df.withColumn("new_column_name", [what put in here?])
```

Answer (score 9):

Assuming your column `original` is boolean :

```
df_new = df.withColumn(~df["original"])  # Equivalent to "not original"
```

Comment: Thanks Pierre, it looks like the '~' operator only works on Boolean Types. This operator is handy though

Comment: Is there something pyspark native to do this? I think if I use ```~``` then it is going to be executed in a python process using memory overhead, not in the JVM. Is there an alternative that will be executed within the JVM only?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be this to be syntax right, based on @pierre-gourseaud's answer:

```
df_new = df.withColumn("new_column_name", ~df["original"])  # Equivalent to "not original"
```